# Change private DNS in AWS without route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I am looking for documentation about changing the private DNS  in AWS. Right now my private DNS is :

> Private DNS ip-172-10-0-17.eu-west-1.compute.internal

`[imagen][1]`

And my objective is "mongo.tfm.org. Is it possible?  I have followed some manuals for change the hostname, but not change the private DNS, like:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html

Is it possible to change the private hostname and do not use route 53.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to change the AWS Default internal DNS if it's already created and bind to an instance. If you need to have your own internal DNS you should create your custom DHCP options set and then bind it to your VPC. 
Instances that will be provisioned using the said VPC will have custom internal DNS that you created.

Route 53 is not necessary in this case because when you create a DHCP option set you will need to provide nameservers(can be an external nameserver eg. corporate nameservers) where your DNS records is serve. Just make sure that the nameservers has the appropriate access rule that allows your AWS resource to ask for DNS resolution.

[image]

[More info here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/dhcp_options_set.html)

Take note that it's an internal DNS, meaning that it's not by default accesible or can be resolved from outside, **unless** your VPC is peered to on-prem network using VPN or Direct Connect.